# Iterate through xml to find url with specific extension with python

Tags: python, xml, regex, xml-parsing

I have an xml file that I download from a url.  I would then like to iterate through the xml to find the link to a file with a specific file extension.

My xml looks something like this:

```
<Foo>
    <bar>
        <file url="http://foo.txt"/>
        <file url="http://bar.doc"/>
    </bar>
</Foo>
```

I've written code to get the xml file like this:

```
import urllib2, re
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

file = urllib2.urlopen('http://foobar.xml')
data = file.read()
file.close()
dom = parseString(data)
xmlTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('file')
```

And then I'd 'like' to get somthing like this to work:

```
   i=0
    url = ''
    while( i < len(xmlTag)):
         if re.search('*.txt', xmlTag[i].toxml() ) is not None:
              url = xmlTag[i].toxml()
         i = i + 1;

** Some code that parses out the url **
```

But that throws an error.  Anyone have tips on a better approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your last bit of code is, frankly, disgusting. `dom.getElementsByTagName('file')` gives you a list of all `<file>` elements in the tree... just iterate over it.

```
urls = []
for file_node in dom.getElementsByTagName('file'):
    url = file_node.getAttribute('url')
    if url.endswith('.txt'):
        urls.append(url)
```

As an aside, you should NEVER have to do indexing manually with Python. Even in the rare instance you need the index number, just use enumerate:

```
mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for i, value in enumerate(mylist):
    print i, value
```

Comment: yeah, it's all kinda gross today.  I just picked up python last week.  But this works perfectly!  Just change the line 'url = file_node.getAttribute('urls')' to 'url = file_node.getAttribute('url')' and it works like a charm.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

An example using `lxml`, `urlparse` and `os.path`:

```
from lxml import etree
from urlparse import urlparse
from os.path import splitext

data = """
<Foo>
    <bar>
        <file url="http://foo.txt"/>
        <file url="http://bar.doc"/>
    </bar>
</Foo>
"""

tree = etree.fromstring(data).getroottree()
for url in tree.xpath('//Foo/bar/file/@url'):
    spliturl = urlparse(url)
    name, ext = splitext(spliturl.netloc)
    print url, 'is is a', ext, 'file'
```